# Trying to plot the markers on google map using GeoJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to print markers on "google maps" using "geojson" for a  given input coordinates.Below attached is the JSON file.

```
{
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features":[{
  "type":"Feature",
   "geometry":
    {
    "type":"Point",
    "coordinates":[-117.7431667,35.9595,0.01]
    }
    }
     ]
```

My Specific problem is i  got 3  parameters in the "coordinates" section  present.I have referred to couple of examples where the "coordinates" have got two parameters.

```
var map;
function initialize() {
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapDisplay'), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    });

    $("#button3").click(function(){

    $.get("http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2015-10-14&endtime=2015-10-21",
       function(data,status){
       console.info("test");
       $.each(data.features, function (i, obj) {
          $.each(obj.geometry, function (ind, obj) {
                if(ind=="coordinates")
                    console.log("key:" + ind + " value:" + obj);
                    var coords = obj;
                    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[2],coords[1],coords[0]);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker
                    ({
                    position: latLng,
                      icon: iconBase + 'schools_maps.png',

                       map: map

                   });


          });
       });
   });
});
 }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 });
</script>
<body>
<div id="mapDisplay">
</div>
<div id="button_Display">
<button id="button1">Sesimic Events last week</button>
</div>
<div id="Sesimic_Events">
<button id="button2">Places affected</button>
</div>
<div id="markers">
<button id="button3">GoogleMarkers</button>
</div>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Below attached is the screenshot of the output   i got when i ran "googlemarkers" button[image: Console.logs while running google markers button]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you overcomplicate this task. Read about the GeoJSON Detail Format here -> http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/geojson_detail.php

Each item of the `features` section of the JSON response is *always* on the format :

```js
{
  type: "Feature",
  properties: {
    //a LOT of properties ...
  },
  geometry: {
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [
      longitude, //<-- you need this
      latitude,  //<-- and this
      depth
    ]
  },
  id: String
}
```

So plotting the earthquake markers is straight forward :

```js
$.get("http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2015-10-14&endtime=2015-10-21",            function(data,status){
  var latLng, marker;
  $.each(data.features, function(i, obj) {
      latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(
         parseFloat(obj.geometry.coordinates[1]), 
         parseFloat(obj.geometry.coordinates[0])
      )    
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: latLng,
         map: map
      })     
   })
})
```

your code simplified and working here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/9p9pk3je/**

Answer (score 1):

For loading and parsing [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) data you could utilize [Data API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer), the following example demonstrates how to load [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) data and place markers:

**Example**

```js
var map;
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false
    });



    map.data.addListener('addfeature', function (o) {
        setMarker(map, o.feature);
    });
    map.data.loadGeoJson("http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2015-10-14&endtime=2015-10-21");

}




function setMarker(map, feature) {
    var latLng = feature.getGeometry().get();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map
    });
}
```

```css
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
```

```html
 <div id="map"></div>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&libraries=drawing&callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>
```