# Google Maps markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer not working with geoJSON

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

Any ideas why my markers aren't clustering? I've tried many different ways and nothing will make them cluster. I realize there might be something wrong with the arguments I'm passing the markerClusterer but I can't find a way to make it work with anything. There's also little to no documentation on markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer (which is required when using unpkg).

```
function initMap() {
    //set map options
    var myMapOptions = {
        center: {lat: 40.7498024, lng: -73.9774375},
        zoom: 12,  
    }
    
    //fill the html div with a map and pass in map options
    var myNewMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mymap'), myMapOptions);
    
    //pass in data
    myNewMap.data.loadGeoJson('missedConnections.geojson');

    //define popup windows
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth: 750, autopanMargin: 10,});
    
    //create new popup windows on marker click
    myNewMap.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
        console.log(event);
        // set variables
        let videourl = event.feature.getProperty('videoURL');
        //padding/margin is wonky on mobile vs desktop
        let html = '<video style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 3px;" preload="none" autoplay width=" 90%"><source src="' + videourl + '"></video>'; 
        // show the html variable in the infowindow
        infowindow.setContent(html); 
        infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
        infowindow.setOptions({pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -30)}); 
        // move the infowindow up 42 pixels to the top of the default marker icon
        infowindow.open(myNewMap);
    });

    new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({myNewMap.data, myNewMap});

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps JavaScript API v3 / Data Layer / MarkerClusterer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25267146/google-maps-javascript-api-v3-data-layer-markerclusterer)

Answer (score 1):

Into your html:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerclusterer/dist/index.min.js"></script>
```

Into your js,  code both of these works

```
var mc = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({ markers, map });
```

or

```
new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({ markers, map });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using [object shorthand incorrectly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015).

Second, that isn't the interface for the library.

```js
const markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer({ map, markers });
```

where markers is an array of `google.maps.Markers`. See [MarkerClustererOptions](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclusterer/interfaces/MarkerClustererOptions.html).

Comment: Thanks, but the documentation states that when using unpkg instead of import I should use markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer ... is that not the case?

Comment: also, my markers aren't in an array, they are in the json file loaded per google's method, is there not some way to use cluster with loadgeojson?

Comment: it takes google.maps.Marker[] and not geojson. you need to convert from geojson to markers

Comment: That doesn't seem right, I can't imagine there isn't a way to do marker clustering using geojson data...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33274429/trying-to-plot-the-markers-on-google-map-using-geojson it's not hard to do the translation from geojson to markers

Comment: Thanks but that is using jquery : \

Comment: jquery is a minor part of the solution there... `$.each(data.features, callback)` becomes `data.features.forEach(callback)`